# Show $\sup\{x: x^2 \in A, x \ge 0\} = \sqrt{\sup A}$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory

$A$ is a nonempty bounded set of nonnegative numbers.

[Proof given in my book](https://ibb.co/SsjPXwf)

My proof:

Let $a \in A$. Then by definition, some $k > 0 \implies 0 \le a \le k$.

Let $x \in B.$ Then $x \ge 0$ and $x^2 \in A$ meaning $0 \le x^2 \le k$ and so  $0 \le x \le \sqrt k$. Thus $B$ is bounded above.

Now, $x \le \sup B$ and so $x^2 \le (\sup B)^2$ and so $(\sup B)^2$ is an upper bound of $A$ meaning $\sup A \le (\sup B)^2$  implying $\sqrt{\sup A} \le \sup B.$

If $x \in A$, then $\sqrt x \in B$. Since $x \le \sup A$ we have $\sqrt x \le \sqrt{\sup A}$ meaning $B$ is bounded above by $\sqrt{\sup A}$. Thus $\sup B \le \sqrt{\sup A}$.

---

Me and my book start from the same premises (say, $x \in B)$ and end up with different conclusions( I end up with $\sqrt{\sup A} \le \sup B$ and the book concludes $\sup B \le \sqrt{\sup A}$). Given that, what am I doing wrong (if anything)? Does my proof work? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both conclusions are correct - you can see that your book proves $\sup B \leq \sqrt{\sup A}$, which is what you got, and then goes on to prove that $\sqrt{\sup A} \leq \sup B$. Combining these two results, you get $\sup B = \sqrt{\sup A}$, which is what you wanted to prove. This is quite a common proof strategy in analysis - to show that $x = y$, it is equivalent to show that both $x \leq y$ and $y \leq x$.